# When I cat a pid file I get a %,why and what that means?

Tags: process, cat

I googled, but it ignore the "%". all about pid.

My system is macOS.

#### Here's the code:

```
cat /usr/local/var/run/php-fpm.pid
#I got this.
7260% 

#When I use vim open it. only have text "7260"
7260
```

Could you tell me why ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you using `zsh`?

Comment: Yes. I use 'oh my zsh'.

Comment: First, I thought the % is about pid. Now i know the % is from ZSH. It's surely duplicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file doesn't finish with a newline, so Zsh appends a reverse-video `%` and a newline itself (both to indicate that the file doesn't end with a newline, and to avoid messing up the following prompt or losing the output entirely).

[Question 3.23 of the Zsh FAQ](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq03.html) has more detail on how to control this, as does [the Zsh manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#Prompting).

Answer (score 0):

In Unix, the line ending is LF (`\n`), when a line is missing that, the next line is tacked to the current line at end as if they were a single line.

This is what happening here, the file `/usr/local/var/run/php-fpm.pid` got a single line with the PID and the line does not end in LF, on most shells yopu would get the next prompt tacked with the output, but here `zsh` is being *smart* and adding a `%` and `\n` indicating the line is missing a LF.

**Example:**

```
foo@bar% cat /proc/self/cmdline
cat/proc/self/cmdline%                                                             
foo@bar% bash
foo@bar$ cat /proc/self/cmdline 
cat/proc/self/cmdlinefoo@bar$
```